# Executing built-in commands

Tags: rascal

I would like to execute an external program from inside a Rascal program without creating a new process using `createProcess()` and `killProcess()`. Is this possible or have I missed something in the documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of calling the `readEntireStream` function:

```
rascal>readEntireStream(createProcess("ls", ["-l","-a"]))
str: "total 192drwxr-xr-x@ 5 jurgenv  admin    170 Mar 24 21:10 .drwxr-xr-x@ 5 jurgenv  admin    170 Mar  3 20:05 ..-rwxr-xr-x  1 jurgenv  admin  25160 Feb  4 18:43 eclipse-rw-r--r--@ 1 jurgenv  admin    637 Apr  3 13:58 eclipse.ini-rw-r--r--  1 jurgenv  admin  64679 Mar 24 21:10 hs_err_pid25121.log"
```

Comment: And this will kill the process once it finishes?

Comment: the streams will be closed and the OS process killed, but there will be some memory leakage if you don't kill the process as well. So to save the int id and also kill it afterwards using `killProcess` would be beneficial. I'll add a convenience function to the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "execute a command": execute a command of the Operating System you are running on, then the answer is *no this not possible*. OS commands are always executed in a separate process. Can you give an example of your use case?

Comment: Not an OS command. The example is I have a program which will format (automatically indent, put things on new lines, etc) Java files. I am using Rascal to produce Java files and I want to format them after they are generated. Thus I want to execute this external program from inside Rascal.  I certainly can `createProcess()` then block until it's finished, which is what I'm doing. I was just wondering if there was another way. Updated my question to change the phrase, 'execute a command'.